# Flask 400 error handler not triggered for bad HTTP request syntax

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that receives bad requests from another software. I would like to manually handle these requests as I can then still call the relevant functions. A sample bad request looks like this `GET GET / HTTP/1.1` with the additional GET in front

Hence, I tried to add a custom error handler as shown in the documentation. However, I am unable to make it work and the default error handler is used instead. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.errorhandler(400)
def handle_bad_request(e):
    print('Custom handler active')
    return 'bad request!', 400


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()'
```

I used Packetsender to send similar bad requests, and Flask receives them and uses the default error handler as I can see in my console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2021 17:49:28] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('GET GET / HTTP/1.1')
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2021 17:49:28] "GET GET / HTTP/1.1" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

So, why is my custom error handler not used? Is this somehow related to the ridiculously incorrect syntax of the requests? Any feedback would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handlers are for unhandled errors in the application code. Sending a bad HTTP request causes an error at the HTTP server layer (the Werkzeug development server in your case, or an HTTP server like Nginx in production). There is no way for Flask or any other WSGI application to handle the errors you're seeing, as the request is invalid, so it doesn't make it to the application layer.